# How to find the closest element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-validate

I have searched in SO I found so many examples but mine was little different from all.

1)  initially i have a row if the user click  save & next button it will say you have 3 fields missing

2) if the user click the addmore button and he did not type any value in the text field then he click the save and next button it should still say 3 fields missing

3) if the user type any one of the field in the cloned row then he click the save and next button validation should happen with my code first two points are working

but the problem is if the user click some more rows and  he type in any one of the cloned field then if he click safe and next button the `required_Field` class was applying in all other field but it should apply only to that row :(

If we can able to find the closest element of the field where the user type then i can able to add `required_Field` class to those element only

I tried like below

```
        function additionalvalidation() {
          var myRow = $(".check").length;

          //$(".cloned_field").css("border","1px solid green");
          $(".cloned_field").change(function() {
                var myField = $(".cloned_field").val().length;
            if (myField >= 0) {
              $(".cloned_field").addClass("required_Field");
              debugger;
              $(".cloned_field").prevAll('label').find('span.required-star').removeClass('text-error-red');
              //bind_validation();
            } else {
              $(this).closest(".cloned_field").removeClass("errRed");
              $(".cloned_field").removeClass("text-error-red");
            }
            bind_validation();
            return false;
          });
        }
```

<strike>With my current code i am getting error.</strike>

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

```
$(this).closest(".cloned_field").addClass("required_Field");
```

I tried this also

```
$(this).closest(".cloned-row1").addClass("required_Field");
```

Any suggestion for this question

I tried this new one ->

```
$(this).closest(".cloned_field").css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});
```

the color red and red border was applying only for that field not for the row :(

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/b0euvnme/3/) for the reference

Comment: Please add your HTML

Comment: `this` refers to `window` in provided example..

Comment: `$(this).parents('.educat_info').after($clone);` isn't working because the `educat_info` DIV isn't a parent of the Add More button. So the clone never gets added to the DOM, and then `$(".cloned_field").val().length` fails because there's no `cloned_field` and `val()` returns `undefined`.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for that can you please update for the last point and can you please check for the third point also i want to add required_field class only for that row not for all the cloned row :(

Comment: @Barmar i have updated the fiddle kindly look the third point

Comment: Why are you doing `$(this).removeClass("required_Field")` in the clone?

Comment: Initially i am removing required_Field because if i required Field was there initially by default without adding any field my validation was happening

Comment: But `bind_validation` only adds validation to fields with that class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98884/discussion-between-mahadevan-and-barmar).

Comment: @RayonDabre any suggestion guys

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/iamsajeev/fg10v39n/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@mahadevan try this code. I working

```
        function additionalvalidation() {
          var myRow = $(".check").length;

          //$(".cloned_field").css("border","1px solid green");
          $(document).on("change",".cloned_field",function() {
          var myField = $(this).val();
          var $clonedDiv  = $(this).closest('.cloned_div');

            if (myField!='') {     
                $clonedDiv.find(".cloned_field").addClass("required_Field");
                $clonedDiv.find(".deg_date").addClass("required_Field");
                $clonedDiv.find(".trans_date").addClass("required_Field");
                $clonedDiv.find(".txt_degreName").addClass("required_Field");


              debugger;
              $(".cloned_field").prevAll('label').find('span.required-star').removeClass('text-error-red');
              //bind_validation();
            } else {
                $clonedDiv.find(".cloned_field").removeClass("errRed");
                $clonedDiv.find(".deg_date").removeClass("errRed");
                $clonedDiv.find(".trans_date").removeClass("errRed");
                $clonedDiv.find(".txt_degreName").removeClass("errRed");

                //$(".cloned_field").removeClass("text-error-red");
            }
            bind_validation();
            return false;
          });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery next maybe the answer for you

> Description: Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

https://api.jquery.com/next/

Comment: with this below code this was working only for current field not for that row 

$(this).closest(".cloned_field").css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});

Comment: i'm on my way to home from work. when i get back home i'll check your issue deeper. hang in there :)

Answer (score -1):

You show know closest search in parents tree and find closest one. If you want to search in siblings you should execute find on siblings.